# Find and replace in VSTO C# function, does not have any provision for making the replaced text bold

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

For find and replace with bold text, I am trying to convert my VBA subroutine to VSTO C# function.

The simple translation from VB to C# does not replace anything (probably because the find text and replacement text have to be passed as parameters to the Execute call and are not picked up from the "oPara.Range.Find" parameters. The modification to supply named parameters, replaces the text but, does not seem to have a way of making the replaced text "Bold". What is it that VB is doing special? How can I achieve it in C#? Setting up the parameters of "oPara.Range.Find" seems to be useless for C#

I have already tried with the code below. The second Execute call in C#, works but then I can not make the replaced text **BOLD**.

```
Sub ReplaceWithBoldInVBA()
    Dim oPara As Object
    Set oPara = Selection.Paragraphs(1)
    oPara.Range.Select

    Dim bFound As Boolean
    With oPara.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Test- "
        .Replacement.Text = "Test: "
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.Font.Italic = False
        .Replacement.Font.Underline = False
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        bFound = .Execute(Replace:=wdReplaceOne)
    End With
End Sub

// Following is the VSTO Add-In C# code 
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
public void ReplaceWithBoldIn_VSTO_AddIn_CSharp() {
    Word.Paragraph oPara = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Paragraphs[1];
    oPara.Range.Select();

    oPara.Range.Find.ClearFormatting();
    oPara.Range.Find.Text = "Test- ";
    oPara.Range.Find.Replacement.Text = "Test: ";
    oPara.Range.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
    oPara.Range.Find.Replacement.Font.Bold = -1;
    oPara.Range.Find.Replacement.Font.Italic = 0;
    oPara.Range.Find.Replacement.Font.Underline = 0;
    oPara.Range.Find.Forward = true;
    oPara.Range.Find.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
    oPara.Range.Find.Format = true;
    oPara.Range.Find.MatchCase = true;
    oPara.Range.Find.MatchWholeWord = false;
    oPara.Range.Find.MatchWildcards = false;
    oPara.Range.Find.MatchSoundsLike = false;
    oPara.Range.Find.MatchAllWordForms = false;

    oPara.Range.Find.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);

    // The following Execute call works but then I can not make the replaced text **BOLD**.


    oPara.Range.Find.Execute(FindText: "Test- ", ReplaceWith: "Test: ", Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne)   
}
```

Comment: i would use the debugger to compare the object `oPara` running in C# compared to VB to start with.  they both end up as IL so I can't see the language being a factor yet

Comment: The second "Find.Execute" call works, when you give it the "findText", "replaceText" parameters with the Execute call. But then what contorted way is there to make the "replaced text" (and only that) correctly bold? The Selection does not automatically shift to the replaced text, which would have helped me to use "Selection.Font.Bold = -1" after the success of the Execute call with parameters explicitly given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason C# is having difficulties is because the exact `Range` to apply `Find.Execute` isn't clear enough. VBA can do it because of the `With` - that association is missing in the C# code.

The following works for me. Notice how specific `Range` and `Find` objects are declared and used to assign the `Find` properties, and the same object is used for `Execute`. (Note: declaring and instantiating `rngFind` would not really be necessary these days. In the early days of C# outside of VSTO it was, using it now is a matter of personal preference.)

```
        Word.Paragraph oPara = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Paragraphs[1];
        Word.Range rngFind = oPara.Range;
        Word.Find fnd = rngFind.Find;
        fnd.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Text = "Test- ";
        fnd.Replacement.Text = "Test: ";
        fnd.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
        fnd.Replacement.Font.Bold = -1;
        fnd.Replacement.Font.Italic = 0;
        fnd.Replacement.Font.Underline = 0;
        fnd.Forward = true;
        fnd.Wrap = Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindStop;
        fnd.Format = true;
        fnd.MatchCase = true;
        fnd.MatchWholeWord = false;
        fnd.MatchWildcards = false;
        fnd.MatchSoundsLike = false;
        fnd.MatchAllWordForms = false;

        fnd.Execute(Replace: Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceOne);
```

Comment: The VBA to C# translator initially converted my VBA With block to a C# with block, where the it had a reference saved into a "withBlock" reference, which it used inside a dummy code block. And it indeed works with that as well. I foolishly converted this with block back to straight code, although inefficient, I could not bear to see a VB like structure. But now i realize it is necessary.
You point out that C# is having difficulties to decide which range to apply Find.Execute to. I want to understand this point in depth. Could you point me to a more detailed explanation?

Comment: Also need to understand some historical perspective on why "rngFind" in your code used to be required in old days.
Please point me to some technical details on in depth of how and why of this aspect of C#. Thanks.

Comment: I've never used any conversion tool to go from VBA to C# - learned it the "hard way", some fifteen years ago. At that time C# had no "with" capability. A "with" block is certainly *not* necessary (any more than it's truly "necessary" in VB - it's more a "nice to have" in that it makes reading and writing code a bit more comfortable.

Comment: I don't know of any documentation or similar for "difficulties...which Range to apply Find.Execute to". It's just something I've learned using VBA and .NET when working with `Find` in Word. Consider: when `Find` is successful, the search range (whether `Range` or `Selection`) is set to the found content. If there is no explicit `Range` object, if something like `Document.Content.Find` is used, the found result canNOT be set to a `Range` - the found range cannot BE the entire document. So `Find` "loses its place" - it can't work with the found range. (Can be put in the answer if it makes sense)

Comment: Again, I don't know of an explicit information source to point you to for delcaring and instantiating objects for the entire hierarchy. The background has to do with managing COM pointers from within the .NET environment. I highly recommend ".NET Development for Microsoft Office" by Andrew Whitechapel. Amazon still has it, I see. It's old but the basics of working with COM Office from within .NET still apply. The reason for the particular remark can be found on Page 40. Mainly, it's a question of being able to correctly manage / clean-up pointers to COM objects that could affect memory.